# How to find uniqueness of data field (eg. Email) every time it is inserted in the database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm developing an android app, in which users enter their name, surname, email and password for registration purpose. This entry process works perfectly fine, now I want to check every time, when a user enters his/her email, that the entered email is exists already in my database or not.

for this I tried the following method in my DBHelper class:

```
public String Exist(String user) {
    String username="";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    try {
        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, "COL_4" + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(user)},null, null, null);

        if (c == null) {
            return username;
        }
        else {
            c.moveToFirst();
            username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_4"));
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e){

    }

    return username;
}
```

here TABLE_NAME is the name of my table, COL_4 is the column which contains emails of the users and I'm passing the entered string (email) entered by user as parameter of this method.

I'm calling this method from my main activity class as following:

```
String myUser = email.getText().toString();
String storedUser = myDb.Exist(myUser);


//If Username exist
        if (myUser.equals(storedUser)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already     exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        }
```

here I'm storing entered email in myUser variable.

The problem is that even the email is entered same as previously entered, it allows to insert the data in database. That means every time the exception occurs and "" is returned. What is error in `Exists` method?

Comment: don't swallow the exception: `catch(Exception e){ }`. If an exception occurs `""` is returned and you know think that the email does not yet exist.

Comment: then what to do when exception occurs?

Comment: and then why every time exception occurs?

Comment: because of a programming error? add the exception to your question

Comment: What is the name of the column? EMAIL or COL_4?

Comment: column name is EMAIL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found answer by myself!
I used following code in DBHelper Class:

```
   public boolean Exists(String user){
    Cursor res = getAllData();
    int flag=0;
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        String email =res.getString(3);
        if(email.equals(user)){
            flag++;
        }
    }

    if(flag==0){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and following code in my main activity:

```
//If Username exist
    if (myDb.Exists(email.getText().toString())) {
        showMessage("Error :(","This username is already exists.");
        return;

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can get that in the query itself
 ***SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Col = 'user email id';***
      If you pass the Table name and column name correctly, it will return the cursor. Below I have put a method which will return true if the email id exists in the table.

```
public boolean isEmailExists(String emailAddress) {
     SQLiteDatabase db =null;   DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  *  FROM Table_name WHERE COLUMN_NAME ='emailAddress';";

            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                 return true;
                }
    return false;
    }
```

As I mentioned earlier appropriate Table name and column name has been given correctly.